# AWS S3 Sync options duplicates / weird behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to sync a folder with 2M+ files to S3, everything went OK but then 40,000 files were not uploaded (server crashed randomly), when I tried to do a sync command again, it started from 0, even if we have 2M-40K images on S3, it re-uploads the 2M images, having "duplicates".

Why I say "duplicates"? Because when I did a list before the re-sync on S3, it said that I had a -40K files difference, when I did after some minutes the re-sync it said it has +80K difference, how is it possible that it has +80K files than origin? **duplicates/versioning/history**

So I'm trying to upload **only** the missing 40k files, because thoose files are at the end of the folder, so if it starts over, it must wait another day to upload the same 2M files...

I hope I've explained it correctly.

**TL;DR:** A broken **sync** command for 2M files against S3 didn't uploaded 40K files, how can I upload **only theese 40k files and not the 2M?**

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario sounds like exactly what the s3 sync tool is supposed to be used for.  I would think "aws s3 sync local_directory s3://your_bucket_location" should work exactly like you're asking.

Are you using the AWS CLI tools?  If so, can you try with --dry-run and let us know if it thinks the difference is ~40k or it is actually all 2M+ files?

EDIT: s3 sync docs, just in case. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Minio client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc), It is open source and compatible with AWS S3.

You can use Minio client ``mirror`command to do the upload. Minio client also has`resume session` command which will upload the object where it was left in last disconnect.

**Example:**

```
$ mc cp  myminio92/atul/yEd-3.15.0.2_with-JRE8.dmg play/kline
....0.2_with-JRE8.dmg: 7.13 MB / 96.19 MB ┃▓▓▓▓█░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░┃   7.42 % 3.00 MB29s mc:  Session safely terminated. To resume session ‘mc session resume KBIJTOtQ’
minio@minio2:~/atul$ mc session resume KBIJTOtQ
....0.2_with-JRE8.dmg: 96.19 MB / 96.19 MB ┃▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓┃ 100.00 % 2.75 MB34s
```

Hope it helps.
Disclaimer : I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)